# Initialize a mysql connection in adonis v4

Tags: javascript, mysql, web, backend, adonis.js

I want to initialize a MySQL connection with credentials that i'm getting from a master database, is possible to do this on AdonisV4?

**using adonis lucid**

I can't set the credentials in config, because they're specific for every request that is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would invoke npm library related to mysql in terminal shell.

```
npm i --save mysql
```

AdonisJs uses the connection value defined inside the config/database.js file. Thus, you may to create a configuration file for a single *database* connection in your *JavaScript* application like following:

[image: database connection code sample]

You can create an initial environment file for your master database like :

```
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=3306
NODE_ENV=development
CACHE_VIEWS=false
```

For several connections, you would setup your config file like this:

```
'use strict'
const Env = use('Env')
const Helpers = use('Helpers')

module.exports = {

connection: Env.get('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql1'),
  
  mysql1: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: Env.get('DB_HOST', 'database_host_1'),
      port: Env.get('DB_PORT', '3306'),
      user: Env.get('DB_USER', 'my_database_user_1'),
      password: Env.get('DB_PASSWORD', 'OhMyAdonis'),
      database: Env.get('DB_DATABASE', 'adonis')
    }
  },
  
  mysql2: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: Env.get('DB_HOST', 'database_host_2'),
      port: Env.get('DB_PORT', '3306'),
      user: Env.get('DB_USER', 'my_database_user_2'),
      password: Env.get('DB_PASSWORD', 'OhMySecondAdonis'),
      database: Env.get('DB_DATABASE', 'another_adonis')
    }
  }
  
}
```

So, you can select any of the connections defined by the database configuration file at runtime with:

```
Database
  .connection('mysql1')
  .table('users')

Database
  .connection('mysql2')
  .table('users')
```

However, if yo have a lot of databases, this approach impacts the RAM server. So, if you have a master database like your case, choose connection dynamically following an ORM for Node.JS using a SQL query builder like [Objection.js](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#multi-tenancy) with knex - based support for MySQL.

A multitenancy approach could be adopted from [here](https://gist.github.com/madrussa/9c0500bc2ecb78ea6ecfc82328a7ce98).

Comment: I can't set the credentials in config, because will be too much credentials.
Any workaround to use .connection()?

Comment: Too much credentials, it is meaning you have not only a single my_database_user_1 for mysql1 and a single my_database_user_2 for mysql2 and so forth ?

Comment: I have a master database with credentials about another other databases, is not the same database, it's different

Comment: I think it would be better to use `npm i mysql2 -S` It is more modern driver.

Comment: A multitenancy approach is not feasible with Adonis V4 with lucid, but it is available on Adonis 5. I will update the answer for a workaround using Adonis V4.